# Eclipse - How to disable "direction" on find/replace dialog

Tags: eclipse, search, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse, when using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> dialog, it is a bit annoying to search for some word in a file and having to select the direction you want to search (forward or backward) or having to put the cursor focus at the top of the file to search forward.

Is it possible to disable this direction option and search for words just like Chrome does? (when searching in Chrome, if you reach the last coincidence and press next again, it will go back to the first one immediately).

Comment: In the _Find/Replace_ dialog check the checkbox _Wrap search_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the *Find/Replace* dialog in the section *Options* there is the checkbox ***Wrap search*** for that.

The *Wrap search* option of the *Find/Replace* dialog is also applied to the *Find Next* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) command.

Alternatively, you can use *Incremental Find* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) which is a *Find* without a dialog: in the *Incremental Find* mode the entered search string is displayed in the status bar and by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> again you go to the next match. On the last match you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> twice to go to the first match.